# how to select children id from parent id in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

Here I have parent div (div1) , by having this id I want to select the children id (children2) .

note :- i dont want to specify as children2 in code .. it should dynamic

Html :-

```
<div id='div1'>

<div id='children1'>
<input></input>
<input></input>
</div>

<div id='children2'>
<input></input>
<input></input>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the IDs are static you can simply use id selector to target the element:

```
$('#children2')
```

If Ids are not unique then you can find immediate div elements in `#div1` along with `:eq(1)` to target second element in matched dom:

```
$('#div1 > div:eq(1)').attr('id')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
$('#div1 #children2')
```

or

```
$('#div1').find('#children2')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#div1').children()
```

will get all child objects in an array.

```
$('#div1 > #children2')
```

will get a specific child object.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate all children using below code

```
$('#div1').children('div').each(function(){
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

More Information on **[.children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/)**

And for getting second child id you can use `nth-child()` like below

```
  var id =  $('#div1 div:nth-child(2)').attr('id');
```

More Information on **[:nth-child()](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)**

Comment: .children will also get inner input elements. should rather use `.children("div")`

Comment: sigh... `$(this).attr('id') === this.id`